# /bin/sh: /user/bin/cc Permission denied

Tags: linux, git, bluehost

I am trying to instal git on buehost shared hosting server.

I am following this blog to install
http://www.willjackson.org/blog/installing-git-bluehost-shared-hosting

But when i run the make command i get the following error..

[image]

Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

You have not permission to compile applications on shared hosting. I think you should try VPS.

**UPDATE:**

In your tutorial author unzips `git-master.zip` to `~/.local/scr/git-master`. So you have `git-master` in `~`. Maybe should try again step by step? I think [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2q8cW9mQtOM) can help you.